# wrapfig2 inside a list

Tags: wrapfigure, parshape, wrapfig2

I know (it is said in the documentation package) that there are problems with wrapfig2 inside a list.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{wrapfig2}


\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}
  \centering\unitlength=1mm
  \begin{picture}(40,30)
        \polygon(0,0)(40,0)(40,30)(0,30)
        \Line(0,0)(40,30)
    \end{picture}
\end{wrapfigure}
texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte
texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte
\item deuxième point
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Here is the result:
[image]

That's not what I wanted because I wanted the figure inside the first item and surrounded by the text.
So, is there a way to achieve that? Maybe with another package or other commands?

Comment: I have not tried, but what if you place it before the first `\item`?

Comment: @mickep `\item` and `wrapfig` both set `\parshape` so they fail in different ways if you change the order but don't make a merged `\parshape` either way. (one day..... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `tcolorbox` package to enclose the paragraph:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{wrapfig2}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \leavevmode\vspace{-2\baselineskip}\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white,boxrule=-1pt,left=0pt]
            \begin{wrapfigure}{r}
                \centering\unitlength=1mm
                \begin{picture}(40,30)
                    \polygon(0,0)(40,0)(40,30)(0,30)
                    \Line(0,0)(40,30)
                \end{picture}
            \end{wrapfigure}
                texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte
                texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte
                
        
        \end{tcolorbox}
        
        \item deuxième point
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: OUTPUT]

Comment: Thank you @miltos. It works perfectly fine

Comment: The two items do not seem to be aligned at the left. Is that some offset thing for the tcolorbox?

Comment: You can control this by passing apropriate negative number to the     `left`    option of     `tcolorbox`

Answer (score 2):

You can protect the paragraph shape with a `\parbox` or `minipage`

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{wrapfig2}


\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item \parbox[t]{\linewidth}{
\mbox{}% get normal line first,for correct alignment

\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{wrapfigure}[8]{r}

\vspace*{-30pt}
  \centering\unitlength=1mm
  \begin{picture}(40,30)(0,-5)
        \polygon(0,0)(40,0)(40,30)(0,30)
        \Line(0,0)(40,30)
    \end{picture}
\end{wrapfigure}
texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte
texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte}
\item deuxième point
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @David. It works perfectly fine